# Unable to run PMD in STS 3.1.0 (uses Eclipse JUNO)

Tags: pmd

I installed Eclipse-pmd plugin in my STS 3.1.0. But the "PMD" option doesnt show up in my STS. couldnt run PMD.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on any Java file in Eclipse, do you see the option for PMD? If you go to Eclipse Preferences, do you see a configuration entry from PMD? If neither of the above it true, then please reinstall the PMD plug-in.

Unlike FindBug or CheckStyle, the PMD plug-in does not pre-configure what rules to check. You have to go to Eclipse Preferences -> PMD -> Rule Configuration and pick which rules you want use.